# Is there a way to turn a string into a usable object?

Tags: python

So I am creating a program that has different possible string outputs. For example, the outputs could either be "a", "b", or "c". However I want to be able to use these outputs as an object. I already have objects initialized as a b and c.  For example:

```
class Letter:
  pass

a = Letter()
b = Letter()
c = Letter()

output = random.choice(["a", "b", "c"])

#for example it would output "a"
#then I would "call" (lack of a better term) the a object to do something with it
#basically the output decides which object I would use

a.color = "green"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make dict to check, which object needs to be used.

```py
ouput = random.choice("a", "b", "c")
output_var_dict = {"a": a, "b": b, "c": c}

output_var_dict[ouput].color = green
```

**OR**

not recommended

```py
globals().update({output: Letter()})
a.color="green"
```

Comment: I think you meant `output_var_dict[output].color = "green"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the objects directly:

```
output = random.choice([a, b, c])

output.color = 'green'
```

*Note that this alerts the original object.*

For working on copies:

```
from copy import copy

l = [a, b, c]
output = random.choice([copy(x) for x in l])

output.color = 'green'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `random.choice([a, b, c])` instead of `random.choice(["a", "b", "c"])`

Which will give you the random object.

Answer (score 0):

Using `eval` you can turn a string into a python object, see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

```
letters = ["a", "b", "c"]
output = random.choice(letters)

char = eval(letters[0])
print(char)
# a
```

To prevent "side effects" of string evaluation you can restrict the scope:

```
letters = ["a", "b", "c"]
output = random.choice(letters)

char = eval(letters[0], {}, dict(zip(letters, letters)))
print(char)
# a  # still works because it is in the dictionary
new_output = 'x'
char = eval(new_output, {}, dict(zip(letters, letters)))
# NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

`x` does not belongs to the local namespace described by the dictionary `dict(zip(letters, letters))`

In your case you should pass as local namespace `dict(Letter=Letter)`